# Badge notification not showing in my tab layout

Tags: android

I am try to show badge notification in my last tab of my application. But I get a `Null Object Reference` everytime and I am not able to understand Why or How. Here I have attached the `badge notification` code line and my TabLayout code Line. Please help me. I am using `VIewBadger` Library for my application.

1. For Badge View

   ```
   tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

   badge7 = new BadgeView(this, tabs, 1);

   badge7.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
   btnTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           badge7.toggle();
       }
   });
   ```
2. MY code to Add Tabs in TabWidget

   ```
       TabSpec spec4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 4");
       spec4.setIndicator("Logout", 
       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_logout)); 
       Intent in4 = new Intent(this, LogoutActivity.class);
       spec4.setContent(in4);

       TabSpec spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 5");
       spec3.setIndicator("Chat", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.messaging)); // custom_logout   logout_icon_test
       Intent in5 = new Intent(this, ChatActivitylisting.class);
       spec3.setContent(in5);
   ```
3. Error Showing

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 
>         'void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(android.view.View, 
>        android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what the issue was. I was declaring the badge even before adding the tabs. i should have declared after "tabHost.addTab("YourTab1..")".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct resource id.

```
tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
```

Comment: hi @Ivan, I have found what the issue was. I was declaring the badge even before adding the tabs. i should have declared after "tabHost.addTab("YourTab1..")". Anyway, thanks for your concern.